# How to draw SPL curve for a parametric equalizer?

Tags: filter, digital-filter, plot

I want to show (graphically) the Gain/Attenuation vs frequency of a parametric equalizer.

This is my circuit:

https://sound-au.com/project28.htm

The same schematicas as a screenshot:

[image]

I want to show the effect of VR1 thru VR7 in the same way as it's shown in the Winamp:

[image]

I have tried to decipher this page: https://www.andyc.diy-audio-engineering.org/parametric-eq-parameters-1.html

I don't know how to interpret the formulas to derive the Gain/Attenuation, given the frequency, Q and center frequency of each equalizer band. Can anybody please explain in simple terms?

Comment: I think my question was not clear. I am working on a project that has several bands of PEQ. I can programmatically alter centre F, Q and boost/cut. Given all these parameters, how do I show to the user what the resulting SPL curve is?

Comment: I am sure its possible to show graphically the effect of the controls on spl. See figure 1 https://sound-au.com/project28.htm.

Comment: I want to show the effect of VR1 thru VR7 in the way its shown in the winamp https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRKVD.png

Comment: I rewrote your question. Now you have a possiblity to get answers instead of  poor mouthing. All comments are now obsolete. Revert freely if you do not like it.

Comment: Instead of trying to plot the spectrum by formulas, you're much, much better off building the schematic in a SPICE simulator ans simulating with `.AC`. That's because the transfer function is very complex, but mostly any variation of the potentiometers will influence the outcome. A simulation will take care of these on the fly (and less error-prone).

Comment: I am controlling a DSP and need to show the effect of the PEQ biquads. The reference to Rod Elliot's site was only to better explain my question. I do not intend to build the circuit at all. I need a simple formula that I can use.

Comment: @wonderfuliot There is no "simple" formula for that behemoth, unless you only need for *one* particular band, in which case you *might* get away with a 2nd order formula. Also, use the ping `@<TAB>` to notify users when replying.